# Angular 2 RC4 Router get intended route before activated

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I am trying to determine what the route is before it is activated so I can cache it and redirect the user back to that route after they have logged in.

In the old beta router I was able to call `ComponentInstruction.routeName` in the activate hook but in the newer `canActivate()` guard I do not see a way to access the intended route before it is activated.

I could store the intended route in a shared service when the user clicks on a navagtion button in my app but what about when they enter the URL in the address bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From angular router source files:

```
export interface CanDeactivate<T> {
  canDeactivate(component: T,
   route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
   state:RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

`ActivatedRouteSnapshot` object (route) has `url` property - array of another type, in first object in property `path` your current path.

Also inside `RouterStateSnapshot` object (state) has just string property `url` with current path, but with `/` prefix on it.

Simply pass those arguments to your canDeactivate method )