# angular2 get route path as title page

Tags: javascript, angular

What's the best way of outputting a **page title** depending on your route path in `angular2` rather than hard-coding the title, I want to output a title in the controller instead.

If user go to `/dashboard` and the dashboard page will have Dashboard title:

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component: dashComponent}
```

Somewhere along:

```
if(path==dashboard){
   title:string = "Dashboard"
} else if(path==something){
   title:string = "Something"
}
```

### HTML Output:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1
```

this logic works but repeating location.path seems a little bit tedious

```
if(this.location.path() == '/order-ahead'){
        console.log('Dashboard')
        this.title = 'Dashboard';
    } else {
        console.log('its something else');
        this.title = 'Something Else'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you should use more complicated logic to achieve more sophisticated solution. For example, using `CanActivated` guard, something like in this ticket: [Angular 2 RC4 Router get intended route before activated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392483/angular-2-rc4-router-get-intended-route-before-activated/38399254#38399254)

Comment: isn't there a simple way? I'm only going to output page titles depending on the url route.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow the guidance in the docs to set the title via the `Title` service:

```
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ Title ])
```

then in your component that has access to the route use something like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  public constructor(private titleService: Title ) { }

  public setTitle( newTitle: string) {
    this.titleService.setTitle( newTitle );
  }
}
```

Here's a link to the docs on this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/set-document-title.html

Comment: but that's setting the html <title>, I'm using <a [routerLink]="/dahsboard"> navigate around. I know in angular1 you can get away with $location.path() == 'url'.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: That's okay, I've edited my original post I can use location.path every if statement but that's hardcoding the path and repeating the process everytime to check the path.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution, subscribe to route changes in the router (example for beta 3.0-2 of router):

```
import { Router, Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

constructor(protected router: Router)
    {
        this.router.events.subscribe(this.routeChanges.bind(this));
    }

    protected routeChanges(event: Event)
    {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            let url = event.url;
        }
    }
```