# Angular 2 Router 3.0 Future Route in CanDeactivate Guard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have written a CanDeactivate guard for my Angular app that's pretty basic:

```
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
    canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate): Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
    }
}
```

It just waits for a promise to resolve to true/false, or an immediate true/false to be passed back in. What I would like to do, however, is in the component where the guard is placed is check the future route. So for example, let's say I have three routes, `/list`, `/shop`, `/checkout`, and I put the `canDeactivate` guard on `/shop`. I want it there because if they go to leave that component, I want to ask them if they're sure they want to leave. But if they're leaving to go forward to checkout, I don't want to ask them if they're sure. I would just return an immediate true to the `canDeactivate` guard. However, if they're going back to `/list`, I may ask them if they're sure they want to leave the items in their cart.

I've looked up several questions, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440025/angular-2-rc5-get-intended-route-in-candeactivate), and read through the docs on the [Angular site](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) but haven't found what I'm looking for.

My thought would be that in the actual component, in the `canDeactivate` method, I would be able to check the router or the future route or something along those lines to see what it is and see if I want to immediately return true from the guard.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: you may add some click handler which uses router.navigate for navigation, and save the URL, which can be used in the `canDeactivate` method to return true\false depending upon your need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a magic, mysterious, optional parameter in the CanDeactivate Interface that will give you exactly what you are looking for...**nextState**

```
interface CanDeactivate<T> { 
  canDeactivate(component: T, currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot): 
  Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean
}
```

SRC :: https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate